# remove index.php : error 404 on linux but work fine on windows

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, codeigniter

Error 404 on linux but work fine on windows. What is causing this?

I use this tutorial: http://www.tutora.fr/apprendre-codeigniter/les-controleurs

**application/config/routes.php :**

```php
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['translate_uri_dashes']  = FALSE;
$route['login'] = 'user_authentification/user_authentification';
```

**application/config/config.php:**

```php
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'CORE_';
```

Local hosting on Windows (XAMPP) works fine at url mysite.dev/login.

Live hosting on Linux produces 404 error at url mysite.pro/login.

If I add `index.php` (mysite.pro/index.php/login), it work fine but I would remove it.

Comment: may be because of several issues.Some of them are file permission issues,  mod rewrite enable/disable,bad CI config etc

Comment: @safin chacko : You're right. I just sent an email to the administrator. I expect ....... to see the flowers grow ;)

Comment: In base url put `http://mysite.pro/`. It is even recommended in [docs](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L20).

Comment: Since this was [not reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35460119/4685471), please delete the thread now.

Answer (score 1):

Create .htaccess file in project root directory if other .htaccess file is not already created.

copy paste below codes into it .

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /projectname
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

You can try this link http://addictors.in/remove-index-php-from-url-in-codeigniter/

**don't forget to restart your server**

Comment: I just tell the administrator to check these lines in virtualhost and change them if the lines do not match and restart apache. I wait
DirectoryIndex index.php  
AllowOverride All  
Order allow,deny  
Allow from all

Comment: The administrator has performed some tests. All is well ;( 
Normally , the .htaccess file should redirect to index.php/login
and mysite.pro/login display on browser. 
codeigniter is not loaded yet

Answer (score 1):

Linux is case sensitive. Keep in mind in which case you wrote the directory and file name. You should write file or directory name in any file exactly same what file or directory belongs.

Please check the file/directory of `user_authentification`. Moreover, the first letter of controller/model should be caps (codeigniter requirements). Please check did you write `controller/model` name correctly.

**Update**

Put the following snippets on `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You're right, it's correctly written. http://mysite.pro/login (404 error), http://mysite.dev/index.pro/login (work fine). I don't understand why...

Comment: did you enable mod_rewrite? if no please enable mod_rewrite and let me know I'll send you some code which should be written on `.htaccess` if you don't have.

Comment: I already had this in my .htaccess file. I just clear my file and left your configuration : no change. I expect an email from the administrator.

Comment: are you on localhost or hosting?

Comment: it's my own hosting. Linux 3.2.0 Debian 3.2.51-1 x86_64.

Comment: just curiosity, don't mind, if it's your own host, how you are expecting email from administrator.  However, could you run `phpinfo();` to check whether mod_rewrite loaded or not.

Comment: The developer is not the administrator. I can send files via FTP but I can not configure apache. This is loaded modules on phpinfo : core mod_log_config mod_logio mod_version prefork http_core mod_so mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_file mod_authz_default mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_mime mod_security2 mod_negotiation mod_php5 mod_reqtimeout mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_ssl mod_status mod_unique_id

Comment: The administrator has performed some tests. All is well ;( 
Normally , the .htaccess file should redirect to index.php/login
and mysite.pro/login display on browser. 
codeigniter is not loaded yet

Answer (score 1):

The administrator has found the error. There was an error in virtual host.
The .htaccess file was never executed.
Thank you all for your help.